# Google play console's pre-launch report didn't start

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

In my experience, the pre-launch report will start automatically as long as I upload my `.apk` file to **Internal test track**. I have uploaded my `.apk` file several days before but the pre-launch report never started, it only shows the message:

> Testing in progress; it can take several hours for these tests to
>   complete. Check again later.

[image]

As it pointed out, "it can take several hours for these tests to complete." I've already waited for it for days and cannot get the result. Are there any settings I should configure to let the test begin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Play Developer Support sent me a mail today, the summary is that their engineers had found some issues and already have it fixed.

In sum, the problem was the bug of Google Play Console.

Answer (score 1):

It may have had an error. When these types of problems occur, after waiting long enough it is always worth contacting Play Console support. You can contact them via the help menu which is on the question mark "?" icon.

Comment: Yeah, I did contact support and they give me a reply today

Answer (score 0):

Last Friday I had the same problem, 2 of my builds were hanging with this status:

> Testing in progress; it can take several hours for these tests to complete. Check again later.

After a few days of searching, I didn't find anything saying that the Play store had any issues. I built a new release and uploaded it again, and the pre-launch report results were in my inbox within no time.

Just resubmit a new release version and wait for a few hours.

Probably the Google pre-launch report had some issues last weekend, but we will never know.

Comment: This method does not solve the problem although it may be worked

Answer (score 0):

No, it seems to be an intermittent error. I had this issue last week when I had an APK in the open Beta channel, and contacted Google Play support several times. After 7 days with no progress, I recompiled my app with a new version number, submitted, and test results were available within the hour.

If after 24 hours there is no pre-launch report, inform Google but don't wait on them --- just submit a new APK build.